# Functional delete command that have a problem, please, read the text before the code. Thanks

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot with discord.js and the case is that I have a command to delete messages from the chat but they can only be used by people who have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission, this command works perfectly but what I don't understand it is because when it detects that this person does not have the permissions, it does not send the message that person does not have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission. Thanks for the help.

```
case 'delete':
        if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Please enter a number of messages you would like to delete like ``k!delete 5``. LIMIT: 100 MESSAGES');
        message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
          return message.channel.send('You dont have the permission `MANAGE_MESSAGES` to use this command!!');
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The command does not work perfectly. Since lines of code are executed in order, currently you are executing the `bulkDelete` before even seeing if the member has permission to do so.

The reason you aren't seeing the error message is likely due to a race condition of sorts: The bulk delete endpoint is handled by a background worker, and likely takes longer to process than your `message.channel.send`. So the message *is* getting sent, but immediately deleted from the `bulkDelete` happening shortly afterwards.

To fix, merely move your `bulkDelete` line after the permission check.